# ¿Puedo crear un objeto con valor en sus parámetros y que todas las clases de la aplicación puedan acceder a ese valor?

Tags: c#, poo

Tengo una duda muy basica de la programacion orientada a objetos: tengo una aplicacion con varias clases. Entonces, ¿hay forma de crear un objeto con valor en sus parámetros y que todas las clases de la aplicación puedan acceder a ese valor?

Pongo un ejemplo de código:

```
namespace Programa
{

    public class Libros
    {
        string atrib1;
        string atrib2;
        string atrib3;
    }


    class MainWindow
    {
        Libros libro1 = new Libros(); 

        libro1.atrib1 = "primer Valor";
        libro1.atrib2 = "segundo Valor";
        libro1.atrib3 = "tercer varlor";

    }

    class OtraClase
    {
        string variable = libro1.atrib1; //da error por problema de visibilidad de bloques

    }

}
```

Comment: Aunque la respuesta que te dieron es correcta, en realidad no deberias hacer eso. La OtraClase deberia recibir en su constructor la informacion necesaria, en este caso el objeto creado. Voy a poner otra respuesta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para lo que planteas creo que lo que buscas es una clase estática de modo que todas las demás clases tengan acceso a ella sin necesitar llamar a su constructor ni nada de eso..

Algo así quizás dentro de tu namespace:

```
static class global
{
    public static class MyStaticValues
    {
        public static string variable= "Hola Mundo";
    }

}
```

Esa variable publica seria accesible por todas las demás clases, e igual que con variables se puede hacer con métodos.

Con tu ejemplo:

```
namespace Programa
{

public class Libros
{
    string atrib1;
    string atrib2;
    string atrib3;
}


public static class MainWindow
{
    public static Libros libro1 = new Libros(); 

    libro1.atrib1 = "primer Valor";
    libro1.atrib2 = "segundo Valor";
    libro1.atrib3 = "tercer varlor";

}

class OtraClase
{
    string variable = libro1.atrib1; //no deberia darte ese problema de visibilidad


    //Quizas en lugar de libro1 deberia ser tambien Programa.MainWindow.libro1.atrib1, pero esto en el momento de asignar el valor a la variable de tipo de string de abajo


}

}
```

Comment: ok,no sabia que el objeto se prodia crear tipo "static", voy a probar y en un instante te comento, muchas gracias

Comment: Te sirvió esta solución?  espero que fuera lo que buscabas o que si no lo era lo encontraras pronto

Answer (score 1):

Aunque hay una respuesta que esta bien, en realidad cuando tengas montones de clases no va a funcionar, ya que no deberias tener un objeto global que englobe todo lo que pase.

Hay algo que se llama responsabilidad, y cada clase es responsable de su información. el caso de un objeto global (y estatico), sirve, pero no deberia usarse para todo tu sistema.

En realidad, tu ejemplo se resuelve pasandole a otra clase, la informacion que necesita cuando la necesita.

Vamos a verlo en codigo (simplificado como en tu ejemplo):

```
namespace Programa
{

    public class Libros
    {
        string atrib1;
        string atrib2;
        string atrib3;
    }


    class MainWindow
    {
        Libros libro1 = new Libros(); 

        libro1.atrib1 = "primer Valor";
        libro1.atrib2 = "segundo Valor";
        libro1.atrib3 = "tercer varlor";
        //Cuando libro necesita usar OtraClase, la instancia
        _otraClase = New OtraClase();
        //y aca, le pasa la info que necesita
        _otraClase.libro = libro1;
        //Tambien le podria pasar esa info en el constructor
        _otraClase = New OtraClase(libro1);
    }

    class OtraClase
    {
        //tiene una propiedad para guardar el libro que le pasaron:
        Libros libro {get; set;}
        //Tambien puede ser una variable, pero mejor una propiedad.

        //En el constructor, podria recibirlo
        Public OtraClase(Libros nuevolibro)
        {
            libro = nuevolibro;
        }

        //y cuando tiene que usarlo, usa el libro que le pasaron
        string variable = libro.atrib1;
    }

}
```

De esta forma, todos los objetos recibiran la informacion que necesiten. No deberias tener un objeto general que no sabes quien lo cambia ni cuando. De esta forma, la información queda contenida a quien le corresponde.

Comment: Existen patrones como Redux, que permiten manejar el eatado global de la aplicación. también los inyectores de dependencia permiten crear valores únicos, y de esta forma el mismo objecto ea usado por todas las clases sin necesidad de andar pasando el dato de clase a clase. Un clase estática con propiedades de solo lectura que solo se creen al inicializarse la clase estática, no debería dar ningún problema.

Comment: seguro, pero esos patrones se usan en aplicaciones con estructuras mas simples. En una app de escritorio, no es tan recomendable, sobre todo en aplicaciones que estan manejando muchos estados y cosas al mismo tiempo. Pero sos libre de escribir una respuesta! @Luis

Comment: Al contrario, Redux (y Flux) nacieron precisamente para lidiar con el estado en aplicaciones web grandes (nacieron en la web, pero se utilizan ya en todo tipo de aplicaciones). Y lo que ayuda en esos patrones, al menos en Redux, es que el estado es inmutable.

Comment: Sos libre de poner otra respuesta. Pero llevar patrones de apps web a escritorio donde las cosas funcionan de otra manera y tenes otro tipo de control es un error. Tenes un ejemplo de una app de escrotorio que use algo asi?

Comment: Muchisimas cosas nacen en la web y se trasladan a otras plataformas (y viceversa), no tiene nada de especial o particular. No estamos hablando de mecanismos intrínsecos a la web, de hecho, el patrón Redux está basado 100% en programación funcional, de ahí que sea inmutable. Si fuese "malo" el uso de Redux en aplicaciones de escritorio, también sería malo usar CQRS y obvio no lo es. Yo mismo lo implementé con Reactive Extensions.Aquí tienes varias implementaciones del patrón Redux para .Net, y ejemplos de aplicaciones donde se utiliza https://github.com/search?l=C%23&q=redux&type=Repositories